# @Url.Action("Action","Controller") calls both post and get method with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller where there are two action methods with same name with HttpPost and HttpGet as shown below , when link with  `@Url.Action("DoSomething","Controller")` is called then both the method are invoked , how do I call only GET method?

Is there anyway to pass type GET or POST in `@URL.Action` or any other way?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DoSomething(int ? MyParam)
{

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(MyModel Model)
{

}
```

In Razor View When I build a link like

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DoSomething","Home",new { MyParam= Whatever})">JustDoIt</a>
```

Then it calls both POST and GET methods, even after specifiying parameter as int and not the model

Comment: How are you using the `@Url.Action()`?  If its in a link that would always be a GET request.  You can POST in a form tag, or POST via javascript

Comment: `Url.Action` just *gives you a URL* - a string. By itself, it's not calling anything.

Comment: We need to see exactly where you are using it. A `string` does not call anything on its own. Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was I was having one more ajax request to check if the page has been loaded completely to show progress bar, when removed that portion of the code from layout, It has been working fine without calling any action method twice.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding post in the form declaration:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSomething","Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

or using HTML:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("DoSomething","Controller")" method="POST">
... 
</form>
```

The HTTP verb POST/GET will route your request to the appropriate action. The default is GET.

Comment: The default is indeed `GET`. Which means that, if they were using the default, they couldn't be reporting the *symptoms* they're claiming to in their question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Have edited my question little, please see if it clarifies.

Comment: @LearningPal An achor tag produces a link which navigates via GET. It will not call your post method. If your post method is getting called, it is from a form submission, not the anchor navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you maybe getting `Url.Action()` confused with `Html.Action()` (apologies if I'm wrong). As someone mentioned in the comments, `Url.Action()` will just render a URL based on the parameters which is intended for say building anchor tags. `Html.Action()` on the other hand will invoke an action when building the page for the response at server side which I'm guessing is what your referring too.

If that's the case, then you will need to specify the Action's parameters for `DoSomething()` by specifying the route values like so:

`@Html.Action("DoSomething", "Home", new {MyParam = 2} )`

The result of `DoSomething(int MyParam)` would be injected into the page. `Html.Action` is not intended to call a `POST` so it's not possible to use this on an Action which has been decorated with the `POST` verb.

Comment: @Html.Action() is taking long and also crashing the page as I am trying to generate a link in for loop..